# HTML Label can not solve icon "&#xf2bc;"

Tags: javascript, html, nativescript

I tried to include the `fa fa-address-card-o` into a Label in a NativeScript application. Sadly he is not resolving it to an icon, but leaving the label empty. When I try it with `&#xf129` (`fa fa-info`) and he could resolve it. Is that an issue with the encoding?

Reference for icons:
https://www.w3schools.com/icons/icons_reference.asp

Not working code:

```
<Label class="fontawesome-icon sidebar-icon"
               col="0"
               row="7"
               (tap)="open(loginPath)"
               (touch)="open(loginPath)"
               text="&#xf2bc;"></Label>
```

Working code:

```
<Label class="fontawesome-icon sidebar-icon"
               col="0"
               row="7"
               (tap)="open(loginPath)"
               (touch)="open(loginPath)"
               text="&#xf129;"></Label>
```

Comment: You can set UTF8 format

Comment: I don't know ns nor react, but is `text` attribute what will be assigned to `textContent` property ? If so, your html entity will not be converted to the utf8 char it should be. You need to set this html entity as the innerHTML of your element.

Comment: It looks like you need to import certain icons to be able to use them with {N}, i'll post an answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could solve this by simply using another icon that was already imported into that "fontawesome-icon"-file. Looks like I can not just use any icons i want in combination with {N}.